# Cannot read property 'connect.sid' of undefined at Layer.session - ExpressJS session

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js

I am having problems using sessions in ExpressJS 4.

I have tried adding session both in server.js (where I set my app's configurations) and in routes.js (where I define my routes). This is what I keep getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect.sid' of undefined at Layer.session [as handle]
(/Users/larissaleite/Documents/Routing/node_modules/express-session/index.js:115:32) at trim_prefix 
(/Users/larissaleite/Documents/Routing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:226:17) at c 
(/Users/larissaleite/Documents/Routing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:198:9) at 
Function.proto.process_params 
(/Users/larissaleite/Documents/Routing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:251:12) at next 
(/Users/larissaleite/Documents/Routing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19) at 
Layer.expressInit [as handle] 
(/Users/larissaleite/Documents/Routing/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:23:5) at 
trim_prefix (/Users/larissaleite/Documents/Routing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:226:17) 
at c (/Users/larissaleite/Documents/Routing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:198:9) at 
Function.proto.process_params 
(/Users/larissaleite/Documents/Routing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:251:12) at next 
(/Users/larissaleite/Documents/Routing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19)
```

I defined the session like this (server.js):

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                                   // create app with express
var connect = require('connect');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var passport = require('passport');

var session = require('express-session');

connect()
  .use(cookieParser('appsecret'))
  .use(function(req, res, next){
   res.end(JSON.stringify(req.cookies));
});

app.use(session({ secret: 'appsecret', saveUninitialized: true, cookie: { secure: true, maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000) }, key:'connect.sid' }));
```

I've also tried removing the key.

When trying to define the session in routes.js, it was like this:

```
app.use(session({ secret: 'appsecret', saveUninitialized: true, cookie: { secure: true, maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000) }, key:'connect.sid' }));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: what version of express are you running? It seems to be express 4, but it wouldn't make sense why you're including connect as well.

Comment: express 4! How should it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove connect all together. Express 4 was a big overhaul that removed connect as a dependency. remove all parts that require / call connect. Also update all your dependencies.

Per the express-session middleware module's docs:
`name - cookie name (formerly known as key). (default: 'connect.sid')`

Don't pass it anything and it will use the express sid. I've copied your code and tested it without connect and I'm not getting those errors. Also, I've added the `resave` key to the `session` config object to mute the deprecated warnings (if you're running the latest express 4 version).

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); // create app with express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var passport = require('passport');

var session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
  secret: 'appsecret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    secure: true,
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000)
  }
}));

app.listen(1234);
```

Comment: @Seth what does this code does ?resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    secure: true,
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000)
  }

Comment: @user7350714 you can find the answers to your questions within their README.md - https://github.com/expressjs/session.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all update your node version to latest version :

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

> Update all dependence packages :

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install
```

> If required

```
npm audit fix
```